# Segmentation fault when more calls come in asterisk

Tags: asterisk, telephony, ivr

I am using asterisk for call handling. Currently we are getting more calls. So when more calls comes asterisk gets killed and we are getting the error message as "Segmentation fault".

Any idea "Why asterisk gets segmentation fault when more calls come?".

Comment: It would help a lot to know which asterisk Version, you have another post where you seem to have some performance problems, is this the same version and setup?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable core dump, after that read dump in debugger to see whats happens.

More info can be found here:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+debugging#Backtracingacoredumpfileintmp

Sorry, c/c++ or asm experience is a must for read that.